# Visual Studio Online: No Reports on Team Server possible?

Tags: excel, visual-studio-2013, tfs, azure-devops

- I have a Visual Studio Online Professional Licence
- I'm using the Team Server (of the online edition, i.e. in the "cloud").
- In Excel 2013, I have the the "Team" Add-in; using this,  I can connect to the Server, and I can retrieve basic lists.

However, when I try the button "New Reports" (in the "team" add-in), then it lets me select the Server, but then I get:

> TF208093: You cannot use work item queries to generate reports  in
>   Excel on this server because it is not configured for reporting.

How to configure the server to avoid this error? Or is this only possible in a stand-alone setup of the team server, and not with Visual Studio online?

Comment: The current version does not support reporting (or process template customization, or SharePoint integration).

Comment: @JohnSaunders What do you mean with "current version"? The "online" version of TFS, or also the standalone version? Why is then there a report button at all?

Comment: The current version of Visual Studio Online.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Reporting on VSO works differently than on TFS. That button will Lilley never work for VSO.

If you go to http://powerbi.com you can pull data from your VSO account and create retorted. It's just source code data for now, but more soon...

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/visualstudioalm/archive/2015/05/04/gain-understanding-and-insights-into-projects-in-visual-studio-online-with-power-bi.aspx

Answer (score 1):

I have been having this same problem. I have a spreadsheet I use to create new work items and it sometimes gets disconnected and all the buttons in the teams tab become greyed out except New Report. But when I try this I get the error described.

To work around this when it happens, **open a new blank excel**, all the teams buttons will appear active, **hit New List and connect it to your server**. **The original spreadsheet's team tab should become active.**